# Why Keras raises shape error in last dense layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I built a simple NN to distinguish integers from decimals, my input data is 1 dimensional array,and the final output should be the probability of integer.
At first, I succeeded when last layer(name:output) had 1 unit. But it raised ValueError when I changed the last dense layer to two units,for I wanted to output both probabilities of number x as integer and decimal.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential,load_model
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
def train():
    t=[]
    a=[]
    for i in range (0,8000):    #generate some training data
        ran=np.random.randint(2)
        if(ran==0):
            y=np.random.uniform(-100,100)
            t.append(y)
            a.append(0)
        else:
            y=np.random.randint(1000)
            t.append(y)
            a.append(1)
    t=np.asarray(t)
    a=np.asarray(a)
    pt=t.reshape(-1,1)  #reshape for fit()
    pa=a.reshape(-1,1)
    pt,pa=shuffle(pt,pa)
   

    model=Sequential()
    dense=Dense(units=32,input_shape=(1,),activation='relu')
    dense2=Dense(units=64,activation='relu')
    output=Dense(units=2,activation='softmax')   # HERE is the problem
    
    model.add(dense)
    model.add(dense2)
    model.add(output)
    model.summary()
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(pt,pa,validation_split=0.02,batch_size=10, epochs=50, verbose=2)
    model.save('integer_predictor.h5')

train()
```

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Can you add the import statements for libraries you have used as well

Comment: Thx for reminding!

Comment: Check my answer. does that solve your error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Since you have 2 outputs, you cant use binary cross_entropy since its a 2 class classification problem. Also, when your inputs are not one-hot encoded you will need `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. If you have one hot features then `categorical_crossentropy` will work with outputs > 1.

Read [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41921/sparse-categorical-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-keras-accuracy) to get more insight into this.

Comment: It works,thx. But though I have two output, it is sill a 2 class classification?(not sure about it)  why binary cross_entropy does not work?

Comment: yes it is because you are now trying to predict the probability for 2 different classes. Depending on the activation (which in this case is softmax), it will return 2 values 0-1 for each of the 2 outputs. If you are doing a binary classification then you are simply using a single output 0-1 which tells you "will the customer clicked on the add (1) or not (0). With 2 outputs its like "will the customer click on the 1st add or the second"